# Question about closed integral on complex plane proof

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, contour-integration, complex-integration, line-integrals

First of all i'm not in the exam (i still need this answer for 6 hours me  and my friend will make some book and i spot weird property in some page. And i just fell sorry if my reader spot it as false statement. My time limit is tomorrow in about 6 hours.) it's not a homework, or something for bad purpose, even not my advantage. **Just ignore the comment**.

If you're still not sure about my question, please give me a clever logic question about proving that my question is real for non bad purpose. For example :

1. If i'm in exam, i will not be able to texting in my laptop or phone.
2. If i'm in exam, i just need the answer for 1-2 hours.
3. If it's a homework, logically there is no more homework considering my uni will change semester, and my lecturer won't give trivial questions like this because of their busy schedule in the last semester.
4. If it's for bad purpose, i would not have thought this far.
5. If i'm lying about the book, i **CAN E-MAIL** the file of my book for you. And my name and my friends are listed there

does that make any sense?  I really need this answer to correct my proof in my book

Sorry for my bad prologue

Before my main question, please take a look about this website on the second paragraph (first proof) :

[Line Integral](https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Calculus/Book%3A_Vector_Calculus_(Corral)/04%3A_Line_and_Surface_Integrals/4.02%3A_Properties_of_Line_Integrals)

> I want to proof:
>
> $$\oint_C M(x,y) \Bbb dx=-\oint_C M(x,y)$$
>
> My proof attempt:
>
> $$\begin{align} \oint_C M(x,y) \Bbb dx &=\int_C M(x,y) \Bbb dx\\
>  &=-\int_{-C} M(x,y) \Bbb dx\\ &=-\oint_{-C} M(x,y) \Bbb dx\\
> &=-\oint_{C} M(x,y) \Bbb dx \end{align}$$

List of my question :

1. Is that property always true?
2. If it isn't, in what cases will it be true?
3. Are complex analytic function under that integration always satisfy that property considering Cauchy Theorem. (Notice it's a closed integral) ($0=-0=0$)
4. Please verify my proof

Somehow, i doubt with my proof.
Please do a correction in specific answer please (if  you have a time).

And please explain with reduce the use of complicated notations. I'm newbie.

Very kind of you if you want to help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why is it urgent?

Comment: Because i'm in deadline :'(

Comment: Ok i'll edit sorry.

Comment: But please trust me. IT'S NOT A HOMEWORK. Even if my proof is false, it won't change my GPA Value. I'm just feel sorry for my reader book if i make a book containing this and appearently it's wrong. My friend give me a deadline and i know this is just whatever for you. But i can't submit wrong information to my book

Comment: Again it really really will not affect my value for God's Sake. It's just a basic question as usual, but my friend waiting for my book. This book will donated for my junior on the next year who will take complex analysis course.  If you don't tell me anything about my mistakes, then you agreed if i give the wrong information. Is this really needed to explain my purpose why i'm asking this question?  Please help me. :'(

Comment: It's NOT for a bad purpose or even my advantage.

Comment: You should trust yourself before asking others to do that. And usually *urgent* type of words does the exact opposite of what they're expected to do.

Comment: Ok, wanna proof? I'm not in exam. And i'm still waiting this answer, even if THIS QUESTION WILL ANSWERED ON THE NEXT YEAR. Haaah.. please. Is there anything i can do to prove that my question is just usual question? Tell me. And basically IF I'm in exam or this is a real homework, i even don't need the answer anymore for 3 hours. Is that clear, make sense? What else? If this forum has feature like video call or something, i will vidcall you to prove my condition..

Comment: And please don't talk about anything else. I just care about MATH here. Thanks, and sorry if my words might be hurt you or something.